# Google AppEngine Search Ranking

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-app-engine-python

When I do a GAE search with limit=20, I am not getting the 20 highest-ranked results, and I am not sure if this is a bug or a known-limitation (feature).

---

Here are my top search results with limit=20 (where first number is the rank, second number is just a related-timestamp to make things easier to read):

```
rank 1589728448 2017-09-03 12:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589780648 2017-09-02 21:30:00
rank 1589786048 2017-09-02 20:00:00
rank 1589786048 2017-09-02 20:00:00
rank 1589804048 2017-09-02 15:00:00
rank 1589807648 2017-09-02 14:00:00
rank 1589807648 2017-09-02 14:00:00
rank 1589814848 2017-09-02 12:00:00
rank 1589814848 2017-09-02 12:00:00
rank 1589865248 2017-09-01 22:00:00
rank 1589870648 2017-09-01 20:30:00
rank 1589876048 2017-09-01 19:00:00
rank 1589879648 2017-09-01 18:00:00
rank 1590416048 2017-08-26 13:00:00
rank 1593852248 2017-07-17 18:30:00
rank 1594282448 2017-07-12 19:00:00
rank 1595326448 2017-06-30 17:00:00
```

And likewise, here are the best-ranking documents from a search with limit=1000:

```
rank 1589721248 2017-09-03 14:00:00
rank 1589728448 2017-09-03 12:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589778848 2017-09-02 22:00:00
rank 1589780648 2017-09-02 21:30:00
rank 1589782448 2017-09-02 21:00:00
rank 1589786048 2017-09-02 20:00:00
rank 1589786048 2017-09-02 20:00:00
rank 1589804048 2017-09-02 15:00:00
rank 1589807648 2017-09-02 14:00:00
rank 1589807648 2017-09-02 14:00:00
rank 1589814848 2017-09-02 12:00:00
rank 1589814848 2017-09-02 12:00:00
rank 1589865248 2017-09-01 22:00:00
rank 1589870648 2017-09-01 20:30:00
rank 1589876048 2017-09-01 19:00:00
rank 1589876048 2017-09-01 19:00:00
rank 1589879648 2017-09-01 18:00:00
rank 1589890448 2017-09-01 15:00:00
rank 1590131648 2017-08-29 20:00:00
rank 1590304448 2017-08-27 20:00:00
rank 1590416048 2017-08-26 13:00:00
rank 1590419648 2017-08-26 12:00:00
rank 1593852248 2017-07-17 18:30:00
rank 1594037648 2017-07-15 15:00:00
rank 1594282448 2017-07-12 19:00:00
rank 1595326448 2017-06-30 17:00:00
```

Notice that there is definitely some overlap...but that limit=1000 returns higher-ranking documents that limit=20 omitted. Almost like limit=20 gave up before it found all the best documents.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I not expect limit=N to return the N-best results?

---

The [Google Appengine Search docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/) state:

> The rank of a document is a positive integer which determines the
>   default ordering of documents returned from a search.

As well as the following about cursors and limits:

> A call to search() can only return a limited number of matching
>   documents. You can repeat the same search, using cursors or offsets to
>   retrieve the complete set of matching documents.
>
> Support paging through the search results by returning only a portion
>   of the matched documents on each query (using offsets and cursors)

I am unclear how paging across results would work here, given that the first page of results (with limit=20) isn't actually guaranteed to be the first 20 results... :/

Comment: I fought with the same thing, I searching and storing search results key in datastore and fetch each group by key. Started a Cron Job to clear them daily!

Comment: Just to double-check..were you fetching 1000 results, and storing that into DB, so that the client could then page through the results as it needed?

Comment: Yeah but not in a DB I put it in app engine datastore. For my case I realize thats simple and cost effective than querying again using a cursor or offset!. And I used a Cron Jobs (Requests that app engine can be forced to make to itself periodically in a specified amount of time!) to clear the search results that have expired. For my case the cron job runs after every 24 hrs